How to configure static file mimetypes in a Blazor WebApp 8
In a Blazor Server Side .net 7 app if you need to handle some particular static files types (eg. a outlook .msg  or something that would be treated as application/octet-stream) you have to configure it in program.cs like this
builder.Services.PostConfigure<StaticFileOptions>(o =>
{
    ((FileExtensionContentTypeProvider)o.ContentTypeProvider).Mappings[".msg"] = "application/vnd.ms-outlook";
});

Unfortunately, this doesn't work anymore in .NET 8, it is confirmed by design, but I cannot figure out how to fix...
Any help?
Thanks

Try to use the code below， not PostConfigure.
var app = builder.Build();
...
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".msg"] = "application/vnd.ms-outlook";

var staticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
};

app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);
...
app.Run();


Yes it works. I didn't try this solution because in .net 7 this was blocking the loading of blazor.server.js file.
But now it seems working. Thanks a lot!
